# Search users by first, middle and last name

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my Rails project I have a table that looks like this:

```
  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",  limit: 255
    t.string   "last_name",   limit: 255
    t.string   "middle_name", limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end
```

and I have a query that search by first_name or by last_name:

```
Person.where("lower(people.first_name) LIKE lower(:q) OR lower(people.last_name) LIKE lower(:q)", q: 'Melanie')
```

And the question is: is there any way to refactor this query to search by first_name, last_name, and middle_name? My database is Postgresql.

**EDIT:**

When I have Person with first_name: Bill and last_name: Gates, and as q I set 'Bill Gates' it will not search proper record. I want to fetch that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
where("lower((COALESCE(people.first_name, '') || COALESCE(people.middle_name, '') || COALESCE(people.last_name, ''))) like lower(?)", "%#{text.split.join('%')}%")
```

Comment: This is great to match first name and/or last name for a rails view

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correct. Just and another `OR` clause for `middle_name`:

```
Person.where("lower(people.first_name) LIKE lower(:q) OR lower(people.last_name) LIKE lower(:q) OR lower(people.middle_name) LIKE lower(:q)", q: 'Melanie')
```

Comment: When I have Person with first_name: Bill and last_name: Gates, and as q I set 'Bill Gates' it will not search proper record.

Comment: Ah! let me update your question. You can go with @Mateusz's answer